# How to save Instagram login between subsequent headless Selenium runs

Tags: selenium, heroku, cookies, google-chrome-headless, chrome-profile

tl;dr chrome profile for Selenium script works on non-headless mode every single time but (sometimes) fails in headless mode.

I have a Selenium python script running every other hour that requires me to be signed into Instagram. Because I’m deploying this on Heroku (and insta forces me to change my password frequently if it detects unusual logins), my script uses a headless Chrome browser to log into insta once (going from the login screen to the insta feed screen) during the first run, creates a chrome profile, and then uses the same chrome profile (with saved cookies etc.) for my subsequent script session runs to eliminate the need to login every time. It also re-logins me in on later runs if it detects that I'm not already logged in as a fallback.

My script always works when when I run it locally on MacOS with `headless=False` - the first run always properly logs in and creates the chrome profile, which is successfully used to go straight to my insta feed in the next runs. However, when I run it locally (or in Heroku) with `headless=True`, the profile sometimes doesn't save my login (and then I end up needing to re-logging in on the next runs).
Here are the options I’m passing into my web driver:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import os

def get_chrome_options(self, headless=True):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222') 
    if headless:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1200x762')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=' + os.getcwd() + '/chrome_profile_1')
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    return chrome_options
```

I'm trying to use the `user-data-dir` option to create the profile if necessary (note that /chrome_profile_1 doesn't exist in the repo before the first run), and retrieve it if it's already present.

I’ve verified that in all of my runs, the driver does reach the insta feed view by the end, so it’s not a problem with my login logic. Even in the times that the login isn’t saved properly, the script still always successfully creates the chrome_profile directory. I tried directly pushing my chrome_profile_1 to my Heroku instance but it doesn't work either (I don't think the Heroku-buildpack-google-chrome is compatible with the profile generated by my local chrome instance).

I’ve also tried adding `driver.close()` and some extra time in addition to `driver.quit()` at the end in case perhaps improper closing of the chrome headless browser is what differentiates the headless vs. nonheadless runs, but that doesn’t seem to solve the issue. Also, I tried adding options like `--profile-directory=, 'disable-dev-shm-usage', --hide-scrollbars, --single-process, --ignore-certificate-errors`.

PS: On a related note, Heroku seems to be discarding the created chrome profile directory in between runs (https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) - once I figure out how to properly create the chrome profile, is there a way to save it between runs on the Heroku instance itself, or must I store it externally and then pull it into Heroku on the next run?